# '.set is not a function' error in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been given the code below to create 100m buffers around solar panels.

`var buff1 = buff130.difference(buff30).set('buffer','100')` generates the error `buff130.difference(...).set is not a function`.

The GEE Debugging Guide (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/debugging) suggests this is a casting error, so I've tried `var buff1 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(buff130.difference(buff30)).set('buffer','100')` to define the type of variable.

This did not work.

Where am I going wrong?

```
var addBuffer = function(Solar_panels){
  //Create buffers 30m buffer around solar panels
  var buff30 = Solar_panels.buffer(30);
  //Create buffers at 100m intervals from the 30m buffer
  var buff130 = buff30.buffer(100);
  var buff230 = buff30.buffer(200);
  var buff330 = buff30.buffer(300);
  var buff430 = buff30.buffer(400);
  var buff530 = buff30.buffer(500);
  var buff630 = buff30.buffer(600);
  var buff730 = buff30.buffer(700);
  var buff830 = buff30.buffer(800);
  var buff930 = buff30.buffer(900);
  var buff1030 = buff30.buffer(1000);
  var buff1130 = buff30.buffer(1100);
  var buff1230 = buff30.buffer(1200);
  var buff1330 = buff30.buffer(1300);
  var buff1430 = buff30.buffer(1400);
  var buff1530 = buff30.buffer(1500);
  var buff1630 = buff30.buffer(1600);
  var buff1730 = buff30.buffer(1700);
  var buff1830 = buff30.buffer(1800);
  var buff1930 = buff30.buffer(1900);
  var buff2030 = buff30.buffer(2000);
  // Subtract consecutive buffers so that have actual 100m buffer
  // Add property to show which buffer is which
  var buff1 = buff130.difference(buff30).set('buffer','100');
  var buff2 = buff230.difference(buff130).set('buffer','200');
  var buff3 = buff330.difference(buff230).set('buffer','300');
  var buff4 = buff430.difference(buff330).set('buffer','400');
  var buff5 = buff530.difference(buff430).set('buffer','500');
  var buff6 = buff630.difference(buff530).set('buffer','600');
  var buff7 = buff730.difference(buff630).set('buffer','700');
  var buff8 = buff830.difference(buff730).set('buffer','800');
  var buff9 = buff930.difference(buff830).set('buffer','900');
  var buff10 = buff1030.difference(buff930).set('buffer','1000');
  var buff11 = buff1130.difference(buff1030).set('buffer','1100');
  var buff12 = buff1230.difference(buff1130).set('buffer','1200');
  var buff13 = buff1330.difference(buff1230).set('buffer','1300');
  var buff14 = buff1430.difference(buff1330).set('buffer','1400');
  var buff15 = buff1530.difference(buff1430).set('buffer','1500');
  var buff16 = buff1630.difference(buff1530).set('buffer','1600');
  var buff17 = buff1730.difference(buff1630).set('buffer','1700');
  var buff18 = buff1830.difference(buff1730).set('buffer','1800');
  var buff19 = buff1930.difference(buff1830).set('buffer','1900');
  var buff20 = buff2030.difference(buff1930).set('buffer','2000');
  // Combine buffers into single feature collection
  return ee.FeatureCollection([buff1,buff2,buff3,buff4,buff5,buff6,buff7,
                               buff8, buff9, buff10, buff11, buff12, buff13,
                               buff14, buff15, buff16, buff17, buff18,
                               buff19, buff20]);
};
```

Comment: ```Solar_panels``` is a geometry I have traced out around the panels in a large solar farm.  The intention is to create 100m wide rings around the panels out to 2km in which to sample Landsat data (calculating average values within the area of each buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the docs tab in the top left,
2. Type "set" in the "Filter methods..." box,
3. See what objects have "set" method. e.g `ee.Feature` or `ee.FeatureCollection`,

So try something like:

```
var buff1 =  ee.Feature(buff130.difference(buff30)).set('buffer','100');
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of just declaring the buffer as a Feature.  So simple.  Thanks!